# nagios plugin webdav check

Tags: bash, linux

I have written a small plugin for nagios to check a WebDAV server. It is supposed to connect using a username and password and upload & delete a test file

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Exit codes
STATE_OK=0
STATE_WARNING=1
STATE_CRITICAL=2
STATE_UNKNOWN=3

FILENAME=/tmp/test_monitor
FILE=test_monitor
HOSTNAME=$1
USERNAME=$2
PASSWORD=$3
WEBDAVDIR=$4

# Verify the type of input and number of values
# Display an error message if the (input) is not correct
# Exit the shell script with a status of 1 using exit 1 command.
[ $# -ne 4 ] && { echo "Usage: $0 <hostname> <username> <password> <webdav_dir>"; exit 1; }

# create temp file
truncate -s 1M /tmp/test_monitor

# connect to server and upload file
curl --fail -T $FILENAME -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD http://$HOSTNAME/$WEBDAVDIR/

status=$?
case $status in
    0)
        echo "OK - File uploaded on WebDAV Server: $HOSTNAME"
        # remove test file
        curl --fail -X DELETE -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD http://$HOSTNAME/$WEBDAVDIR/$FILE
        exit $STATE_OK
        ;;
    1)
        echo "CRITICAL - Cannot upload file on $HOSTNAME"
        exit $STATE_CRITICAL
        ;;
    6)
        echo "CRITICAL - Could not resolve host $HOSTNAME"
        exit $STATE_CRITICAL
        ;;
    26)
        echo "CRITICAL - Cannot open $FILENAME for upload"
        exit $STATE_CRITICAL
        ;;
    22)
        echo "CRITICAL - The requested URL returned error"
        exit $STATE_CRITICAL
        ;;
    127)
        echo "CRITICAL - Command not found"
        exit $STATE_CRITICAL
        ;;
    *)
        echo "UNKNOWN - "
        exit $STATE_UNKNOWN
esac
```

Can you suggest any improvements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, the code is clean and easy to follow.  I appreciate the consistent indentation.  I would not be upset about running your code in production.  Here are some suggestions that would make it even better:

## use your own variables

With the lines

```
# create temp file
truncate -s 1M /tmp/test_monitor
```

we get a temporary file, but since we name it explicitly it isn't clear that it gets used by the curl right after.  It would be easier to follow if you did:

```
truncate -s 1M $FILENAME
```

If you want to be really careful, check the exit value of `truncate` or see if the file is the right size (which also implies that it exists).

## check before assigning

You assign your command line arguments before checking if they are even there.  I prefer to check before using so I would like to see:

```
# Verify the type of input and number of values
# Display an error message if the (input) is not correct
# Exit the shell script with a status of 1 using exit 1 command.
[ $# -ne 4 ] && { echo "Usage: $0 <hostname> <username> <password> <webdav_dir>"; exit 1; }

HOSTNAME=$1
USERNAME=$2
PASSWORD=$3
WEBDAVDIR=$4
```

## for usage exit UNKNOWN rather than WARNING

If somebody runs your plugin within nagios without enough command line arguments your script will print the helpful usage and then `exit 1` which we know nagios will interpret as a warning.  That's something that could get missed in a big nagios install for a while so I'd prefer to `exit $STATE_UNKNOWN` so that it will be obvious in nagios that something is broken with the config.

## duplicate variables

From your script:

```
FILENAME=/tmp/test_monitor
FILE=test_monitor
```

I understand that you need this in different places, one without the path, and otherwise with the path.  But we can reduce duplication by doing something like

```
FILE=test_monitor
FILENAME=/tmp/$FILE
```

I would go one step further and rename the variables as

```
FILENAME=test_monitor
FQFN=/tmp/$FILE
```

now `FILENAME` contains the name of the file without the path and `FQFN` is he "Fully Qualified File Name" and is the one you will mostly use.

## tips for nagios plugin writers

For writing a nagios plugin in any language I would encourage folks to:

- include a sampling of `command` config entries
- maintain your code on github so you get a free issue tracker and such
- register with the icinga registry since the nagios one has been broken lately

## btw

The locals don't like it if you revise your code in the same post.  So if you want another review, please start another thread.  Dropping a link to the new one in the comments here is also nice.  `:-)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have updated the script in a new post here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118884/nagios-plugin-webdav-check-2

Answer (score 2):

Nice script!

In addition to @chicks' great review, I suggest to eliminate the duplication in the `curl` commands. They both share `curl --fail -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD` and the base URL `http://$HOSTNAME/$WEBDAVDIR`.

- Create `BASEURL=http://$HOSTNAME/$WEBDAVDIR` and reuse
- Create a `_curl` function that calls `curl --fail -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD "$@"`, and replace your current calls with:

  - `_curl -T $FILENAME $BASEURL/`
  - `_curl -X DELETE $BASEURL/$FILE`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have updated the script in a new post here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118884/nagios-plugin-webdav-check-2